# Why do my dictionary values have '\' in them?

Tags: python, dictionary, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

I am reading a dictionary into python that was saved into a csv. I am reading with this code:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('out.csv', 'r'))
d = {}
for row in reader:
   k, v = row
   d[k] = v
```

and getting this result ...

```
{'results': '[{\'alternatives\': [{\'transcript\': \'\', \'confidence\': 0.0, \'words\': []}], \'language_code\': \'en-us\', \'channel_tag\': 0}, {\'alternatives\': [{\'transcript\': "okay so okay I\'ll 22nd yes let\'s use my phone cool thank you all right let\'s get the clock up here yeah 20 seconds okay so we\'re going to be calm and relaxed and chill and just sit still for twice I guess no problem all right ready yep", \'confidence\': 0.9024933, \'words\': [{\'start_time\': \'7.700s\', \'end_time\': \'8.200s\', \'word\': \'okay\', \'confidence\': 0.0, \'speaker_tag\': 0}, {\'start_time\': \'8.500s\', \'end_time\': \'9.500s\', \'word\': \'so\', \'confidence\': 0.0, \'speaker_tag\': 0}, {\'start_time\': \'9.600s\', \'end_time\': \'9.800s\', \'word\': \'okay\', \'confidence\': 0.0, \'speaker_tag\': 0}, {\'start_time\': \'9.800s\', \'end_time\': \'9.900s\', \'word\': "I\'ll", \'confidence\': 0.0, \'speaker_tag\': 0}, {\'start_time\': \'9.900s\', \'end_time\': \'10.400s\', \'word\': \'22nd\', \'confidence\': 0.0, \'speaker_tag\': 0}, {\'start_time\': \'10.400s\', \'end_time\': \'10.600s\', \'word\': \'yes\', \'confidence\': 0.0, \'speaker_tag\': 0}
...
```

What's with the \ characters showing up? When I view the raw file in the termianl (`cat out.csv`), I get this:

```
results,"[{'alternatives': [{'transcript': '', 'confidence': 0.0, 'words': []}], 'language_code': 'en-us', 'channel_tag': 0}, {'alternatives': [{'transcript': ""okay so okay I'll 22nd yes let's use my phone cool thank you all right let's get the clock up here yeah 20 seconds okay so we're going to be calm and relaxed and chill and just sit still for twice I guess no problem all right ready yep"", 'confidence': 0.9024933, 'words': [{'start_time': '7.700s', 'end_time': '8.200s', 'word': 'okay', 'confidence': 0.0, 'speaker_tag': 0}, {'start_time': '8.500s', 'end_time': '9.500s', 'word': 'so', 'confidence': 0.0, 'speaker_tag': 0}, {'start_time': '9.600s', 'end_time': '9.800s', 'word': 'okay', 'confidence': 0.0, 'speaker_tag': 0}, {'start_time': '9.800s', 'end_time': '9.900s', 'word': ""I'll"", 'confidence': 0.0, 'speaker_tag': 0}, {'start_time': '9.900s', 'end_time': '10.400s', 'word': '22nd', 'confidence': 0.0, 'speaker_tag': 0}, {'start_time': '10.400s', 'end_time': '10.600s', 'word': 'yes', 'confidence': 0.0, 'speaker_tag': 0}, {'start_time': '10.600s', 'end_time': '10.800s', 'word': ""let's"", 'confidence': 0.0, 'speaker_tag': 0}, {'start_time': '10.800s', 'end_time': '11s', 'word': 'use', 'confidence': 0.0, 'speaker_tag': 0}, {'start_time': '11s', 'end_time': '11.100s', 'word': 'my', 'confidence': 0.0, 'speaker_tag': 0}, {'start_time': '11.100s', 'end_time': '11.400s', 'word': 'phone', 'confidence': 0.0, 'speaker_tag': 0}, {'start_time': '11.400s', 'end_time': '11.600s', 'word': 'cool', 'confidence': 0.0, 'speaker_tag': 0}, {'start_time': '11.600s', 'end_time': '11.900s', 'word': 'thank', 'confidence': 0.0, 'speaker_tag': 0}
```

which seems right.

I just want to be able to parse this by keys like a normal python dict. For reference, I saved the dict from google speech to text api, using this:

```
import proto

# response variable comes from normal google speech to text workflow
response_json = proto.Message.to_dict(response)
with open('out.csv', 'w') as csv_file:  
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for key, value in response_json.items():
       writer.writerow([key, value])
```

Comment: You're not reading a CSV file.  You're reading a JSON file.

Comment: They are escape characters, used to indicate a single quote character literal that should not delimit the end of a string.

Comment: I don't know the `proto` api, but in your writer, `value` appears to be a complicated data structure. `writerow` will write a string representation of that data. You could `print(repr(value))` just before writerow to see what that is. Now you have to decide how to pull that data out in to a columnar format for the CSV file. Or decide to use a different serialzier like json or pickle to save the data.

Comment: Your first and second result values are the same - just encoded differently. Similar to the numbers 1000 and 10^3 - they are the same numbers just encoded differently. The primary item with your results is the characters used to start a string and the characters used to defined keys/values inside that string. **\'** is an escape for the single quote character which means use it literally and not as a string start or termination character.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you convert the .CSV files to JSON format. [Here](https://datatofish.com/csv-to-json-string-python/) you can see step by step how to convert to JSON.

This is a sample code to convert .csv to JSON:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv (r'Path where the CSV file is saved\File Name.csv')
df.to_json (r'Path where the new JSON file will be stored\New File Name.json')
```

You need to add this code before the “FOR” statement where you read the “response_json.items()”

This is a sample code:

```
import proto 
# response variable comes from normal google speech to text workflow 
response_json = proto.Message.to_dict(response) 
with open('out.csv', 'w') as csv_file: 
writer = csv.writer(csv_file) 
/*
Convert to JSON format
*/
for key, value in response_json.items(): 
writer.writerow([key, value])
```